# Error to send mail on SMTP on WordPress (Connection timed out)

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, phpmailer

Versions:

```
WordPress: 4.8.5
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 5.4.45
WP Mail SMTP: 1.2.5
```

Params:

```
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Host: smtp.yandex.ru
Port: 465
SMTPSecure: ssl
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(false)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)
```

Server:

```
OpenSSL: Yes
Apache.mod_security: No
SMTP Debug:
2018-04-03 10:39:37 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465, timeout=300, options=array (
)
2018-04-03 10:44:37 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465 (Connection timed out)
2018-04-03 10:44:37 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
2018-04-03 10:44:37 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the connection is being blocked by your webhost (unless you are hositng yourself) as lots of hosts do not allow fopen(). Do you have access to your php.ini file?

Comment: Yes, i can open php.ini